# Should we burninate [moderation]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just found the [moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderation) tag. It has 79 questions (4 closed) and 2 followers.

Some of the questions are about some kind of statistics thing, but most of them are about moderating social networking type things. A lot of the questions are too broad or are about a problem specific moderation tool and don't have an MCVE.

Let's moderate this tag.

Comment: Probably just this [completely unrelated meta post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3678/16724) makes me a little sour on the title. ;)

Comment: Most of the questions with this tag are down-voted anyway

Comment: Oi... moderators... leave those tags alone!

Comment: I thought that most of the postings were actually regarding the statistical term: "moderation". If you're going to "burninate" it then perhaps you should allow substitution of "moderator variable" or "moderation model" for the statistical use.

Comment: @42- Most of the questions on the first page are, but most of the questions on later pages aren't.

Comment: Fine. I offered an alternate couple of options if you think the majority goes the other way. I also took a stab at actually offering a definiton which at the moment seemed up-for-grabs..

Comment: Requesting a rename of this question to `We don't need no [moderation]`

Comment: No dark sarcasm in the chatroom...

Comment: Removing this tag would threaten the moderator-industrial complex. They will never allow it. There may be unfortunate accidents among those of us who read this question.

Comment: Oh God... I saw the new title and thought, "Oh, hey, Floyd reference! I wonder if anyone realizes..." Reading the comments, my mind nearly exploded from brilliance. I knew there was a reason to love this community. This tag may be just another brick in the wall, but the commentors here most certainly aren't.

Comment: Anyone can explain to me how a 79 question tag can become a brick in the wall? I can chew through those 79 questions while I cook some pasta :/

Comment: Get a shovel http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[moderation]+closed%3A0+answers%3A1+score%3A0

Comment: Posts regarding the statistical terms `moderator variable` or `moderation model` can just use a more general [tag:statistics]. Anything too in-depth on those concepts would probably be better suited to Math.SE.

Comment: @brandaemon: Note that the [process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags) referenced in the italics at the top of the current edition of the question explicitly says that the joky title will be replaced with a straight-laced one at this stage in the process.

Comment: What happened to the Floyd-esque question title? :-(

Comment: @Leight See step 2 of [Burnination Process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/1529630): Any punny titles will be replaced with, "Should we burninate [name of tag]?"

Comment: @Oriol - Bummer. The punny titles are usually what draws attention. I would never have read this thread in the first place with its current title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

##This tag is now burninated! Thanks to everyone that contributed to this effort!

---

## Progress

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments.

Please note that:

> - Posts regarding the statistical terms moderator variable or moderation model can just use a more general tag [statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics). Anything too in-depth on those concepts would probably be better suited to [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

> - Moderation questions related to [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) probably refer to a comment moderation tool, which is not a programming tool. Integrating/activating that tool on a site is a very specific thing that does not need a separate tag. [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) or [facebook-comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-comments) should be sufficient replacements if needed.

Here are some easy links to get you started:

[moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderation)

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmoderation%5D+closed%3Ano) 0
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmoderation%5D+closed%3Ayes) 0
- [No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmoderation%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmoderation%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0

[Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=moderation)

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority!
If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), or leave a comment under this post.

Comment: Post are coming out of the 2 day limit on deletion for <20k users

Comment: And Battleship icon. Burninated!